# Recommended period for archiving boarding passes?

Tags: air-travel, tickets

Should I throw away any paper boarding passes after landing and collecting my luggage? Or are there any considerations why it is recommended to keep them archived for some period of time? (For how long?)

Comment: I keep everything until I am safely back home.

Comment: Based on some other questions/answers here, you should probably keep them until after you have passed border control, if doing so.

Comment: Keep them at least until the miles show up on your frequent flyer account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no time required to keep them. Throw them away whenever you want.

It is better to still keep them digitally, even in an old email.

Some uses for keeping them:

- Claiming compensation
- Travel record history
- Memory logbook
- Bookmarks (paper only)
- Claiming miles for flights
- Future discounts (either on flights or other perks offered by the airline)

If you do bin them, dispose responsibly  to not reveal any private information. Even your barcode could contain information about you.

If there is no electronic access whatsoever even online with the reference, i recommend keeping them for a few months and then it's your choice if you want to keep them for memories/other uses.

Comment: What about those passes which were printed at the check-in or transfer desk so there is no a access to their electronic version?

Comment: @miroxlav if there is no electronic access what-so-ever even online with the reference, i recommend keeping them for a few months and then its your choice if you want to keep them for memories

Comment: @miroxlav ok, if my answer helped please upvote it by clicking the top arrow and/or pressing the tick. Thanks

Comment: Sure and thanks, but I'd like to prefer the recommended way (in help center) - to wait for some time before taking such actions.

Comment: @miroxlav ok, no problem